# Markdown editor with edit and view mode

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a OS X markdown (or similar) editor that has an edit and a view mode. I want to view the rendered document by default and have an edit mode to change the content. Just in the way most wikis work.

[Day One](http://www.dayoneapp.com) uses edit/view modes but it doesn't let me edit arbitrary text files.

On iOS I found [Trunk Notes](http://www.appsonthemove.com/trunk.htm).

I am not looking for an editor with a preview. I want to see either Markdown or rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an app. [Write for Mac](http://writeapp.net/mac/) supports preview on opening.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Ulysses](http://www.ulyssesapp.com) if you’re looking for editing and preview in one app.

[image: Ulysses Screenshot]

However, I usually write with [iA Writer](http://www.iawriter.com/mac/) and use [Marked](http://markedapp.com) to preview them in Markdown. Use whichever you prefer.

[image][image]

Comment: I tried Ulysses yesterday and it was the best I've found so far. But it doesn't have a true view mode in the way Day One does.

Comment: I think you can combine [Marked](http://markedapp.com) with your favorite text editor. You can assign shortcut in Marked to enter **Edit Mode** with pre-determined text editor.

Answer (score 1):

[MOU app](http://mouapp.com/) is also pretty good. It has side-by-side edit and preview windows, and is free-/donation-ware. (Not sure what you mean by render preview — actual HTML or PDF as would be output by Pandoc?)

Comment: Something like Mou without the two panels. I see either the preview (default) or the markdown (edit mode). But not both at the same time.

Comment: Interesting request. Sounds like the original Adobe Illustrator. In MOU, you can toggle the live preview with Command-Shift-I, but I don't think you can toggle the editing window on/off to just see the preview. I like having them side-by-side, but then my monitor is big enough to see each full size. Sounds like your best bet would be a Marked preview window on top of an editor window and switch between apps.

Answer (score -1):

Haroopad, http://pad.haroopress.com
It's great app for markdown.